# Should we flag posts that are obviously preaching as spam?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Sometimes we get posts that are not really trying to ask or answer a question. Instead, they intend to use the SE as a platform for preaching.

Examples:

- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35242/3961
- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35152/3961
- [Answer on *Where in the Bible does it say that God doesn't have forms?*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/35222/3961)

I do not think these are genuine posts and I would bet that the users are not going to come back to make them better and probably won't even post again.

These seem like spam to me. They are effectively an advertisement, though not a traditional "buy this" kind of pitch. I would be in favor of swift deletion, as we are with traditional spam.

Comment: Define "obviously"...

Answer (score 5):

meh, meh and maybe?

None of these are exactly spam in the traditional sense, they aren't really offensive they're just...off with respect to the tone we generally expect here.

With questions like these, generally all we need to see is close votes, and that's what we have with these two questions. No need for flags here.

With answers like the one your linked, you still have to judge it by whether or not it answers the question within the defined scope, if it does, then you can try to edit it to be less preachy, if it doesn't (and typically posts like this don't), then flag it for deletion as Not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I see these questions as trolling, not as spam.  They aren't trying to sell anything, they aren't polluting our web site with links.  People should cast down-votes, close-votes, and delete-votes as normal.

Comment: But *not* flag?

Comment: I don't see any reason to flag it, unless it's also overtly offensive, in which case the appropriate flag is 'offensive'.